# CSS Style Issue with Content Slider and Last Pic

Tags: css

I have implemented a Content Slider and made some style changes.

http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/5tXgQ/

I also added an additional Thumb Pic (the 7th on the Right) and Main Pic.

For some reason, the Slider skips this Thumb Pic- why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it's a problem with your counting. Try the following

```
// ... *snip*
    theInt = setInterval(function() {
        $crosslink.removeClass("active-thumb");
        $navthumb.eq(curclicked).parent().addClass("active-thumb");
        $(".stripNav ul li a").eq(curclicked).trigger('click');
        curclicked++;
        if( 7 == curclicked )
            curclicked = 0;

    }, 3000);
};
// *snip* ...
```

Notice I've changed the line `if(6 == curclicked)` that resets to zero if the number of clicked thumbs *exceeds* the quantity of thumbnails (i.e. look to see if it's 7 instead of 6) instead of just equalling them.

Comment: Thanks I relized the other issue

Answer (score 0):

You have seven images, but tell it to jump to first image after the first six.

```
curclicked++;
    if( 6 == curclicked )
        curclicked = 0;
```

Change it to 7 instead of 6 and it will work.